# My code will append a list but not print out the correct length

Tags: python, list, append, string-length

I'm using PyCharm and I have to append and then print out the length of the list. But instead of giving me 4 for all the elements it is giving me 2 for each separate list. I'm not sure what the issue is:

```
my_list = ['ABC, GHI, JKL']

print('My first list', my_list)

my_list.append('MNO')

print('My appended list', my_list)

print('My list size', len(my_list))
```

Comment: `mylist` is initialized as a list with one string element as 'ABC, GHI, JKL'

Comment: `'ABC, GHI, JKL'` is just one item inside list.

Comment: Thank you to everyone that answered!!!

Answer (score 0):

`my_list` is a list of one element, because the container is `'ABC, GHI, JKL'` which is one string.

So you need a list with three elements at start as `['ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL']`.

Then your code will work as expected.

The output of the code would be:

```
My first list ['ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL']
My appended list ['ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO']
My list size 4
```

Which is as desired.

Answer (score 0):

`my_list` originally has only one element (notice the start and end of quotes). If there is only one pair of quotes and no other elements as integers or floats, there is only one element in list.

To get a 4 output, you need to split your first element on `', '`, like so:

```
my_list = ['ABC, GHI, JKL']

my_list = my_list[0].split(', ')    # <--- 

print('My first list', my_list)
my_list.append('MNO')
print('My appended list', my_list)
print('My list size', len(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code absolutly works correct,
The reason you got 2 as output is that you have given Items as a single string into your list, it means your list has single item of 'ABC, GHI, JKL' and then you append your second list item 'MNO'. Meanwhile should you correct your list at first line, sprating each item using , or using ' within , sperators.

```
my_list = ['ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL']
len(my_list)
3
my_list.append('MNO')
len(my_list)
4
```